# Read set text from (game) screenshot in real time

Tags: .net, graphics, ocr, text-processing, real-time-data

I'm working on a project to read set text phrases from a running game's on-screen console (via a periodic screenshot) in real time.

Example on-screen Minecraft console screenshot:

[image: img]

Would this be best done with an OCR library? Or can I out perform OCR by searching for set pixels on a scanline (using C#) as I have set phrases (pixel patterns/strings?) to search for? If so can any graphics gurus point me in the right direction.

**Edit: This needs to work on Windows 7**

Comment: If you're pulling console data from Minecraft, this is stored in a log. Even a single player instance runs a "server", which is how Open to LAN works.  That's what you want to read, not attempt OCR in realtime on a pixellated font.  http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/server-support/server-administration/1923720-how-to-check-my-server-logs

Comment: @user1895086 Minecraft is just an example. My target games don't have a log file.